# Using ThreadPool in the program

Tags: java, linux, jdbc, threadpool

Hi i have java program with JDBC,I have used threads in that but i am gettin exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1964" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I think because i am starting the threads infinitly and not closing also

so,i want to use thread pool ,sp that thread come from the pool and after performing the task it go pack to the pool.

This is my java code:

```
public class DBTestCases{

    Connection localConnection; 
    Connection remoteConnection;
    Connection localCon;
    Connection remoteCon;
    List<Connection> connectionsList;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String dbName = "myDB";
    String connectionUrl1= "jdbc:mysql://11.232.33:3306/"+dbName+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
    String connectionUrl2= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbName+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";

    public List<Connection> createConnection() {

        try {
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    localCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl2);
                    if(localCon != null)
                        System.out.println("connected to remote database at : "+new Date());
                    remoteCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl1);
                    if(remoteCon != null)
                        System.out.println("connected to local database at : "+new Date());
                    connectionsList = new ArrayList<Connection>( 2 );
                    connectionsList.add( 0 , localCon );
                    connectionsList.add( 1 , remoteCon );
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                    cnfe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
                        sqle.printStackTrace();
                        }
        return connectionsList;
    }

    public void insert(){

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
        PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
        PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
        String sql = "insert into user1(name, address, created_date)" +
                                " values('johnsan', 'usa', '2013-08-04')";
        if(remoteConnection != null&&localConnection != null) {
            System.out.println("Database Connection Is Established");
            try {
                        ps1 = remoteConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        ps2 = localConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        int i = ps1.executeUpdate();
                        int k = ps2.executeUpdate();
                        if(i > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data Inserted into remote database table Successfully");
                        }
                        if(k > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data Inserted into local database table Successfully");
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException s) {
                            System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                            s.printStackTrace();
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
            System.out.println("Inserting values in db");
        }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void retrieve(){

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
        try {
                    Statement st1 = localConnection.createStatement();
                    Statement st2 = remoteConnection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
                    ResultSet res2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
                    System.out.println("---------------------------Local Database------------------------");
                    while (res1.next()) {
                        Long i = res1.getLong("userId");
                        String s1 = res1.getString("name");
                        String s2 = res1.getString("address");
                        java.sql.Date d = res1.getDate("created_date");
                        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s1 + "\t\t" + s2 + "\t\t"+ d);
                    }
                    System.out.println("------------------------Remote Database---------------------");
                    while (res2.next()) {
                        Long i = res2.getLong("userId");
                        String s1 = res2.getString("name");
                        String s2 = res2.getString("address");
                        java.sql.Date d = res2.getDate("created_date");
                        System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s1 + "\t\t" + s2 + "\t\t"+ d);
                    }
        } catch (SQLException s) {
                System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                s.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBTestCases dbTestCases = new DBTestCases();
        List l = dbTestCases.createConnection();
        dbTestCases.localConnection = (Connection)l.get(0);
        dbTestCases.remoteConnection = (Connection)l.get(1);
        for(;;) {
            dbTestCases.insert();
            dbTestCases.countRows();
            dbTestCases.retrieve();
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me how i should modify this program  to using thread pool..so that i will not get that exception

Thankyou in advance

Comment: http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/thread-pool-executor-example-j2ee, in most cases you need to have JDBC connection pool as well to make sure threads do not get blocked on the JDBC socket. Your program looks like an attempt to DoS both local and remote systems though.

Comment: yes i want my program to access  and manipulate both remote and local databases at the same time.

Comment: DoS is Denial of Service - it will flood both services with commands.

Answer (score 0):

For a thread pool use an ExecutorService:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

For example a ThreadPoolExecutor:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html